# Google / iPhone outputs differ, iphone has a lot of white space

Tags: html, css, iphone, viewport

Viewport doesn't seem to be correctly working on my cell phone, I'm unsure why it starts zoomed out with a pile of **white space** along the right-hand side of the screen (but appears as intended while on Google simulator).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1" />
```

Iphone Output

[image: iphone image]

Google Iphone

[image]

Website Address - http://foodmachineryaustralasia.co.nz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to the CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I used the style (although, it doesn't seem to change anything). But I'll up vote you.